# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()" because "this.flag" is null

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

I'm trying to use Jackson in case to serialize and then deserialize an object. The object contains a field -> `protected Serializable data`
This is where the problem comes from - this data can come from a lot of components. That is why I'm trying to configure the Jackson ObjectMapper instead of adding annotations and changing the code (because for some of the issues I have with the serialization, like this one, I have to change like hundreds of different classes). Is there any way to tell the ObjectMapper to not use `.booleanValue()` on null fields.
This is how I've currently configured my ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    objectMapper.setVisibility(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when your object has a property definition of type `Boolean` but a getter of type `boolean`.  Ensure these types match.